# jQuery validation plugin - Don't show required messages

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) on my page and have the following code for `errorPlacement`:

```
errorPlacement: function(err, el) {
  err.insertAfter(el);
}
```

Works as intended but for the required fields I don't want the default message to show up for the required rule. So if Email has rules for `required` and `email`, I only want the error message to display if it is for the `email` rule, not the `required` rule. Is there a way to disable just the required message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#myForm').validate({
    rules: {
       myField: {
            required: true,
            email: true
       }
    },
    messages: {
       myField: {
            required: "",
            email: "my email rule error message"
       }
    },

    //  my other options & configuration parameters
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `required` from rules and leave `email`.

Comment: What if he wants the field to still be required?

Answer (score 0):

I set the required message to `''` as Sparky672 suggested and just added a check for an empty tag before I insert the error element.

```
errorPlacement: function(err, el) {
  if(err.text() !== '') err.insertAfter(el);
}
```